# Form resize and image size syncing

Tags: c#, image, winforms, gdi+

I'm busy implementing some image resizing operations. The gist of it is for every 1 pixel the form resizes, the image will resize by 1 pixel. For now, I have only implemented width reduction. I have an overridden `Panel` that I use to paint my image in `OnPaint` method.

I am listening to the `From.Resize` and I'm doing the width reduction in there. When that is done, I call `Invalidate` on my custom `Panel` which redraws the image. This all works.

As you can imagine the form resizes quicker than what my image reduction code runs and that is fine. If I take my time and resize slowly, then the `Form` size and image size stay in sync but if I do a "hard" resize, the `Form` quickly becomes smaller than the image. It seems resizing does not block UI thread.

Is there some way I can "block" or slow down the resizing so the two can stay in sync width wise?

Comment: It is a very simple GUI usability rule, if the user provides input faster than the GUI code can keep up then the user always wins.  In this case, you simply won't get a Paint event.  And of course it needs to work this way.  It is such a common hazard that there is an event for it.  The ResizeBegin event tells you to stop making it look perfect.  And ResizeEnd to tell you to get pretty again.  It might look a bit dorky in between, but the user usually understands.  He can tell from the bill that he didn't hire 20 devs.

Comment: So unless you have some very trivial code, don't try and do something realtime in `Resize` event then?

Comment: You realize `PictureBox` has all this functionality built-in, right?

Comment: @nyerguds No it doesn't.